# Stop jquery effect?? Or stop the javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have a big ul list. Like this:

```
<ul class="eerstelaag">
    <li class=""><a title="?" href="/">? (14)</a>
        <ul class="tweedelaag" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="/">Roerstaafjes</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Thee favorieten</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Siropen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a title="?" href="/">? (14)</a>
        <ul class="tweedelaag" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="/">Roerstaafjes</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Thee favorieten</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Siropen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a title="?" href="/">? (14)</a>
        <ul class="tweedelaag" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="/">Roerstaafjes</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Thee favorieten</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Siropen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And i have this javascript:

```
$(function()
        {
            var button = $("#assortiment ul.eerstelaag > li");

            button.hover(function()
            {

                if( button.hasClass("open"))
                {
                    var menuitem = $(this).find("ul"); 
                    menuitem.slideUp(600);

                    button.removeClass("open");     
                }
                else
                {
                    var menuitem = $(this).find("ul"); 
                    menuitem.slideDown(600);

                    button.addClass("open");

                }
            });
        });
```

When i hover over the first li item. Then the ul in that li is coming and show. But now come the problem. When i going fast hover over the li items. The effect i going crazy. And when i going hover faster and faster. It is a crazy effect.

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for the [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function, which will cancel any currently-running animations on the element. You'd use this on the [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) of the element you're about to animate.

---

**Update**: Re my comment below, it looks like avoiding chaotic behavior is much trickier than simply stopping the animation. Here's a rough take:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var button = $("#assortiment ul.eerstelaag > li"),
      opening = null,
      closing = null;

  button.mouseover(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        open;

    if (!$this.hasClass('open')) {
      // If there's an active close operation, cut it short
      if (closing) {
        closing.stop().css("height", "").hide();
        closing = null;
      }

      // If there's an active opening operation, turn it into
      // a closing operation
      if (opening) {
        closing = opening;
        opening = null;
        closing.stop().css("height", "").slideUp(600, clearClosing);
      }

      // Is any sibling open? If so, unmark it it...
      open = $this.siblings('li.open');
      open.removeClass('open');
      if (!closing) {
        // ...and since the sibling wasn't still actively
        // opening (that's handled above), close it
        closing = open.find('ul:first');
        closing.stop().css("height", "").slideUp(600, clearClosing);
      }

      // Open
      $this.addClass('open');
      opening = $this.find('ul:first');
      opening.slideDown(600, clearOpening);
    }
  });

  // Callback used when we're done closing, to clear
  // our tracker
  function clearClosing() {
    if (closing && closing[0] === this) {
      closing = null;
    }
  }

  // Callback used when we're done opening, to clear
  // our tracker
  function clearOpening() {
    if (opening && opening[0] === this) {
      opening = null;
    }
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/origu4/2)

Note that when stopping the animation, I had to explicitly clear the `height` because it could get left in an intermediate state by `slideUp` / `slideDown`. You could probably use classes for tracking the actively opening/closing items, rather than the vars I used.

I should mention that in the above I went with putting the "open" class on the `li` containing the `ul`, whereas in your original, the "open" class was on the `ul` itself. If it was purely a marker (you weren't using it in your stylesheets), great; if not, I expect you could modify the above to go back to using the "open" class on the `ul`, or update the stylesheets to use `li.open > ul` selector instead of the `ul.open` selector to style them.

Comment: @Mike: menuitem.stop().slideUp(600); for example

Comment: @Mike, @Andy: Glad it worked for you. I was still able to get some fairly chaotic behavior in my quick test, but if you don't, great! I just have this nagging suspicion there's a refactoring in here we could do... I think you're going to tend to get odd behavior when using `mouseenter` (via hover) for this stuff, since you're moving elements around and so the element may move under (or out from under) the mouse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when i add the .stopp to the function. Then are li items that have not the good height. When is hovering over the li items. The height of the li items is every time going smaller and smaller.....

Comment: @Mike, @Andy: FYI, got the chaos a *bit* under control. (The problem interested me...)